# "object not found error" from eval inside a function

Tags: r, eval

I am using a shorthand for string eval that behaves differently in different contexts. The function I am using is

```
teval = function(string,...){
    eval(parse(text = string), ...)
}
```

When running this function from the global environment, it works as expected, having access to the environment variables. eg:

```
a = 3
teval('a')
```

will always return 3

`teval` inside a function on the other hand has different behaviour depending on R version

```
tevalyFun = function(){
    a=3
    teval('a')
}

tevalyFun()
```

will give the `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'a' not found` error. or will return the `a` defined outside the function. I am asking for an explanation of what is happening and a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can specify the `envir` in `teval` as `environment` (using `R 3.3.0`)

```
a <- 231
tevalyFun = function(){
   a=3
  teval('a', envir = environment())
}

tevalyFun()
#[1] 3
```

Comment: According to the manpage, parent.frame() should be default... but I'm on R 3.2.4. environment() should also work right?

Comment: this does not work as intended. it prints out the a in the global environment not the one created inside the function. try removing a from your global environment. If you do `a=231` then `tevalyFun()` you'll get 231 not 3

Comment: @Carton if it does not work as intended then you should provide an example that shows what is intended instead of complaining.  I am just showing that there is no object 'a' found error

Comment: if you use environment() instead of parent.frame() here, it works @Carton

Comment: Sorry I thought it was obvious that I wanted to print the variable defined inside the function.

Comment: Anyone has any idea why is this happening? environment indeed works

Comment: @Carton the `parent.frame` search for the parent environment ie. global environment and find that value while the enviornment looks for 'a' inside the function.